# are there any API for the EPUB standard?

Tags: epub, api

I want to work on personal project working with books and magazines. I was wondering if there were any APIs for the [EPUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) standard. That are open to the public.

Please and thank you

GC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know of any freestanding API as such, but [FBReader](http://www.fbreader.org/) supports EPUB so it might be worth looking through the sources of that and see if you might be able to extract the EPUB bits easily.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need the API to do for you. Create books, parse books, mine text in books? I'm confused as to why you would mark as correct an answer which points to a reader--how could that help? You are probably looking for things such as https://code.google.com/p/python-epub-builder/.